# Querying data in MicroStrategy by REST API's

Tags: api, report, metadata, microstrategy, dossier

I'm working on MicroStrategy Project. I need to retrieve the metadata and underlying data used by existing reports and dossiers (could be created from outside of the organization and imported into my Intelligence Server, which means I don't have the data source available directly) through REST APIs.

I found the REST APIs family in this page https://lw.microstrategy.com/msdz/MSDL/GARelease_Current/docs/projects/RESTSDK/Content/topics/REST_API/REST_API_API_families.htm, and tried the libraries, reports, dossiers APIs, but the result is not what I expected. Could someone suggest which API I should try out?

I also notice that the GET api/search/results can probably be a solution, but I'm having difficulty to find the correct int for the types, subtypes and extTypes from the TypeTable (https://lw.microstrategy.com/msdz/msdl/GARelease_Current/docs/ReferenceFiles/reference/com/microstrategy/webapi/EnumDSSXMLObjectTypes.html#DssXmlTypeTable). Any suggestion for the int of types I should try would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have a lot more luck querying both the metadata and data within the objects using the newer Library Rest API. Here is a link to the documentation, which is much clearer and provides the opportunity to test out some of the code using MicroStrategy's demo server:

[MicroStrategy REST](https://demo.microstrategy.com/MicroStrategyLibrary/api-docs/index.html?visibility=all#/)